# Why Some records are missing when using parallel.forEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my code,i'm getting list of menus from database and map them to `DTO` objects,
due to nested child,i decided to use parallel to map for mapping entities,but i bumped into a weird issue ,when `forEach` is finished some of the records are not mapped !

The number of missed records are different each time,one time one and another time more !

```
public List<TreeStructureDto> GetParentNodes()
{
    var data = new List<TreeStructureDto>();
    var result = MenuDLL.Instance.GetTopParentNodes();
    Parallel.ForEach(result, res =>
    {
        data.Add( new Mapper().Map(res));
    });
    return data;
}
```

but when I'm debugging I'm getting

number of my original data is 59

[image]

But after mapping, the number of my final list is 58 !

[image]

My mapper class is as follows:

```
public  TreeStructureDto Map(Menu menu)
{
    return new TreeStructureDto()
    {
        id = menu.Id.ToString(),
        children = true,

        text = menu.Name,
        data = new MenuDto()
        {
            Id = menu.Id,
            Name = menu.Name,
            ParentId = menu.ParentId,
            Script = menu.Script,
            SiblingsOrder = menu.SiblingsOrder,
            systemGroups = menu.MenuSystemGroups.Select(x => Map(x)).ToList()
        }
    };
}
```

I appreciate your helps in advance.

Comment: Adding to `List` is not thread safe

Comment: why?! what is the alternative

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Comment: Why? Because `List` is not thread-safe. You can either use a thread-safe container or (probably better) try PLINQ with `Select` and `ToList`

Comment: maybe SynchronizedCollection<T> ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: Why i got down vote !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding to a single list concurrently, which is not valid because `List<T>` is *not* thread-safe (most types are not thread-safe; this isn't a fault of `List<T>` - the fault is simply: never assume something is thread-safe unless you've checked).

If the bulk of the CPU work in that per-item callback is the `new Mapper().Map(res)` part, then you may be able to fix this with synchronization, i.e.

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(result, res =>
{
    var item = new Mapper().Map(res);
    lock (data)
    {
        data.Add(item);
    }   
});
```

which prevents threads fighting *while adding*, but still allows the `Map` part to run concurrently and independently. Note that the *order* is going to be undefined, though; you might want some kind of `data.Sort(...)` **after** the `Parallel.ForEach` has finished.

Comment: But i'm creating a new instance per every thread. it means Map part is thread safe and there is no problem ,isn't?

Comment: BTW the OP can use ConcurrentBag<T> if he want a more thread safe way

Comment: just locking add to list part should solve the problem

Comment: @Abolfazl the problem is the `data.Add`, which is not thread-safe regardless of where the value came from. I can't comment on your mapper, but *assuming you didn't do anything terribad* (like shared mutable static fields), then *on the surface*, the `new Mapper().Map(...)` should mean that they are isolated and independent (which is a very different discussion as to whether it is "thread-safe", but that's probably being pedantic; the point is: yes, the `Map(...)` part *should* be fine, but that doesn't change a word I said)

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel whether or not something like that is *beneficial* is hugely contextual, though

Comment: thank you buddy! it needs to be considered some conceptual aspects in understanding multithreading

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to locking inside a `Parallel.ForEach` would be to use PLINQ:

```
public List<TreeStructureDto> GetParentNodes()
{
    var mapper = new Mapper();
    return MenuDLL.Instance.GetTopParentNodes()
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(mapper.Map)
        .ToList();
}
```

`AsParallel` uses multiple threads to perform the mappings, but no collection needs to be accessed via multiple threads concurrently.

As mentioned by Marc, this may or may not prove more efficient for your situation, so you should benchmark both approaches, as well as comparing to a single-threaded approach.

Comment: it is an interesting and worthy suggestion - definitely one to know about, but whether that is *more efficient* than locking is a very complex topic. The things that PLINQ does to orchestrate things *aren't free*; conversely, a `lock` over an `Add` is *incredibly cheap*. So: definitely interesting, but I suspect it is actually *more* expensive (not less), but perhaps more *convenient*. As has been said: if you want to know for sure which horse is faster, you'll need to race the horses; https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/